# If statement running every second

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, setinterval

This is a really simple question, I'm building a timer in React JS and I want to know if this is right.

There is a setInterval() on my app that every second decreases 1 to my "seconds" state, which is this one:

```
const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0)
const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(0)
const [isPaused, setIsPaused] = useState(true)

timerId.current = setInterval(() => {
    setSeconds(prev => prev - 1)
}, 1000);
```

And this useEffect checks EVERY SECOND if the timer is running AND if seconds is < than 0, to increase minutes and adds 59 more seconds.

```
useEffect(() => {
    // if timer isn't running return
    if (isPaused) {
        return
    }

    // reset seconds and decrease minutes
    if (seconds < 0) {
        setSeconds(59)
        setMinutes(prev => prev - 1)
    }
}, [seconds])
```

My question here is, isn't it bad for the useEffect to run two if statements every second? Like, wouldn't it be bad for performance?
And if it really is bad, what other options do I have?

Comment: Running code every second is not an issue in itself provided that code only takes milliseconds to run, as yours likely does. But in your specific case, your `useEffect` will be causing 1-2 additional renders, when you can surely update both minutes and seconds in the one function to cut down on that. (Assuming React batches the updates, which isn't a given.) Also the code you have here starts a new interval on every render, without apparently ever clearing any, which is going to lead to heaps of problems. So I assume this isn't your real code anyway?

Comment: Can you give me an example of a function to update both minutes and seconds? (about the interval, I wanted to make it simple so I didn't type the function that triggers it)

Comment: It would just combine the minute's calculation you've already got in the `useEffect` with the code in the interval function. Although I realise now you can simplify it further - just keep a single state variable of the total seconds, and compute minutes and seconds from that inside the render body.

Comment: @ScottMarcus While this may be on-topic on CR, in the future, please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *Needs more focus*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353)

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ I disagree with your comment. There is a specific reason for closing a question that is the the question belongs on another Stack site, however the list of choices doesn't include CR (which it should), so instead I choose what I chose. I believe it is entirely appropriate in this case as the OP is not asking about solving a coding issue, but rather looking for best practice.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ I understand and you're decision making process for why you voted to close it is up to you. I'm very comfortable with my reasoning and how I approached this.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Keep in mind that if your same logic is applied on CodeReview, they will also close the question, because it can be answered on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Andreasdetestscensorship Again, I am comfortable with my close vote. I have been a member here for over a decade. I get how it works.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Ok, but then you should be prepared to defend your view if somebody brings it up on Meta, or if a moderator disagrees. But hey, we all gotta do that for our actions. I’m not bringing it up anywhere, though.

Answer (score -2):

```
const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0)
const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(60)
const [isPaused, setIsPaused] = useState(true)

useEffect(() => {

   const time = setIntervel(() => {
   setSeconds(pre => {
     if(pre === 0) {
        setMinutes(pre => pre + 1)
        return 60
     } 
     return pre - 1

   })
   }, 1000)
   if(isPaused){
      clearIntervel(time)
    }
   
}, [isPaused])
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.